# Is it possible to create a content security policy that allows all websites to be accessed?

Tags: content-security-policy

I have been having problems with scripts not getting loaded because of problems with content security policy settings and was wondering if there was a way to set a content security policy so that it lets all websites be accessible for downloading scripts?

Comment: That defeats most of the point of the policy.  What problem are you having?

Comment: Yes I agree it is not a good idea but it would help me make progress until I can sort out why I can't access the google maps api script no matter what content security policy I try.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13228825/34397

Comment: I tried those suggestions but none worked for me. Hence the question about turning off content security.

Comment: Why not? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not sure exactly what Content Security Policy you need, it's fine to start with a policy that's very permissive, (which is at least better than no policy at all) and refine it.

For example,

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src *
```

would allow you to include scripts from anywhere, but everything else, for example images, only from your own site.

I would also recommend you start with Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only, which reports errors but doesn't block the content.  That way you can safely test and refine your policy before you enforce it.

See for example Scott Helme's blog article
https://scotthelme.co.uk/content-security-policy-an-introduction/

Comment: Thanks Chris that was exactly what I was looking for.